# How to optimise a slow double integral in python that uses a lot of interpolation? Perhaps using Numba?

Tags: python, optimization, interpolation, numba

I desperately need to speed up some code that includes a double integral with 1D interpolation in both steps. I've reduced it to the following minimum working example:

```
import numpy as np

from scipy.interpolate import interp1d as interp
from scipy.integrate import romberg


def calculate_p22(k):
    data='input_data.dat'
    data=np.loadtxt(data, unpack=True)
    p_int = interp(data[0], data[1])
    lnqmax=np.log(0.2*k)
    lnqmin=-9.0
    result=romberg(dq, lnqmin, lnqmax, args=(k, p_int))
    return result


def dq(lnq, k, p_int):
    q=np.exp(lnq)
    integral_theta=romberg(dtheta, 0.0, np.pi, args=(q, k, p_int))
    return q**3.*p_int(q)*integral_theta


def dtheta(theta, q, k, p_int):
    p=np.sqrt(k**2.+q**2.-2.*k*q*np.cos(theta))
    return p_int(p)
```

Calling romberg does raise accuracy warnings, but the results are correct to a level I am happy with. Even with increasing the tolerance, the code still remains slow. I tried to understand how to use Numba, but I came up against the difficulty that Numba cannot use interp1d. I searched for alternative Numba interpolation functions online, but had the difficulty that they require you to give the desired x values for output when calling the function. Scipy.interpolate.interp1d is better for adaptive integration functions because I can create the function and then calculate values within the integrand function on the fly.

I would really appreciate some help with speeding this up (either Numba or non-Numba related tips would be great!). I have been working on the expanded version of the code for a couple of weeks and am considering just rewriting everything in C or Fortran. But I would much rather get this working!

Thank you.

---

Update: Here is the output from cProfile:

```
         19720831 function calls (19700522 primitive calls) in 20.513 seconds

   Ordered by: standard name

   ncalls  tottime  percall  cumtime  percall filename:lineno(function)
        1    0.000    0.000   20.513   20.513 <string>:1(<module>)
        1    0.000    0.000    0.000    0.000 _iotools.py:31(_is_string_like)
     7666    0.003    0.000    0.028    0.000 _methods.py:31(_sum)
  1054196    0.364    0.000    2.274    0.000 _methods.py:37(_any)
   527098    2.182    0.000    4.804    0.000 _util.py:192(_asarray_validated)
   527098    0.212    0.000    0.484    0.000 base.py:1111(isspmatrix)
   527098    0.195    0.000    0.358    0.000 core.py:6192(isMaskedArray)
        1    0.000    0.000    0.000    0.000 fromnumeric.py:1143(squeeze)
     7666    0.025    0.000    0.056    0.000 fromnumeric.py:1730(sum)
        2    0.000    0.000    0.000    0.000 fromnumeric.py:55(_wrapfunc)
        1    0.000    0.000    0.000    0.000 fromnumeric.py:70(take)
        1    0.000    0.000    0.000    0.000 fromnumeric.py:826(argsort)
   527098    1.120    0.000    2.605    0.000 function_base.py:1934(interp)
        1    0.000    0.000    0.000    0.000 interpolate.py:298(_check_broadcast_up_to)
        2    0.000    0.000    0.000    0.000 interpolate.py:315(_do_extrapolate)
        1    0.000    0.000    0.000    0.000 interpolate.py:403(__init__)
        1    0.000    0.000    0.000    0.000 interpolate.py:511(fill_value)
   527098    0.348    0.000    2.953    0.000 interpolate.py:545(_call_linear_np)
   527098    1.182    0.000    9.746    0.000 interpolate.py:603(_evaluate)
   527098    2.489    0.000    5.250    0.000 interpolate.py:618(_check_bounds)
     1025    0.010    0.000   20.492    0.020 minimum_example.py:17(dq)
   526073    2.759    0.000   19.557    0.000 minimum_example.py:23(dtheta)
        1    0.000    0.000   20.513   20.513 minimum_example.py:7(calculate_p22)
        1    0.000    0.000    0.000    0.000 npyio.py:718(_getconv)
     1792    0.002    0.000    0.002    0.000 npyio.py:721(floatconv)
        1    0.005    0.005    0.018    0.018 npyio.py:748(loadtxt)
        2    0.000    0.000    0.000    0.000 npyio.py:858(<genexpr>)
        1    0.000    0.000    0.000    0.000 npyio.py:906(flatten_dtype_internal)
 1792/896    0.004    0.000    0.004    0.000 npyio.py:935(pack_items)
      897    0.003    0.000    0.004    0.000 npyio.py:951(split_line)
        1    0.000    0.000    0.000    0.000 numeric.py:1432(rollaxis)
     9718    0.017    0.000    0.022    0.000 numeric.py:2135(isscalar)
  1588963    0.792    0.000    1.410    0.000 numeric.py:463(asarray)
   527100    0.219    0.000    0.367    0.000 numerictypes.py:660(issubclass_)
   527100    0.481    0.000    0.946    0.000 numerictypes.py:728(issubdtype)
        1    0.000    0.000    0.000    0.000 polyint.py:105(_reshape_yi)
        1    0.000    0.000    0.000    0.000 polyint.py:113(_set_yi)
        1    0.000    0.000    0.000    0.000 polyint.py:133(_set_dtype)
        1    0.000    0.000    0.000    0.000 polyint.py:55(__init__)
   527098    0.844    0.000   16.836    0.000 polyint.py:62(__call__)
   527098    0.557    0.000    5.545    0.000 polyint.py:88(_prepare_x)
   527098    0.429    0.000    0.701    0.000 polyint.py:94(_finish_y)
        1    0.000    0.000    0.000    0.000 py3k.py:94(is_pathlib_path)
  9718/12    0.589    0.000   20.494    1.708 quadrature.py:117(vfunc)
  8692/11    0.063    0.000   20.495    1.863 quadrature.py:544(_difftrap)
    36282    0.029    0.000    0.029    0.000 quadrature.py:570(_romberg_diff)
   1026/1    0.082    0.000   20.495   20.495 quadrature.py:596(romberg)
     1026    0.001    0.000    0.001    0.000 quadrature.py:88(vectorize1)
        1    0.000    0.000    0.000    0.000 re.py:192(compile)
        1    0.000    0.000    0.000    0.000 re.py:208(escape)
        1    0.000    0.000    0.000    0.000 re.py:230(_compile)
   527098    0.363    0.000    0.483    0.000 type_check.py:251(iscomplexobj)
      221    0.002    0.000    0.002    0.000 {_warnings.warn}
    15332    0.003    0.000    0.003    0.000 {abs}
     7668    0.002    0.000    0.002    0.000 {getattr}
  2125781    0.797    0.000    0.797    0.000 {isinstance}
  1581305    0.367    0.000    0.367    0.000 {issubclass}
        1    0.000    0.000    0.000    0.000 {iter}
   536565    0.059    0.000    0.059    0.000 {len}
  1054196    0.487    0.000    2.761    0.000 {method 'any' of 'numpy.ndarray' objects}
    38074    0.008    0.000    0.008    0.000 {method 'append' of 'list' objects}
        1    0.000    0.000    0.000    0.000 {method 'argsort' of 'numpy.ndarray' objects}
        1    0.000    0.000    0.000    0.000 {method 'close' of 'file' objects}
        1    0.000    0.000    0.000    0.000 {method 'disable' of '_lsprof.Profiler' objects}
        2    0.000    0.000    0.000    0.000 {method 'endswith' of 'str' objects}
        1    0.000    0.000    0.000    0.000 {method 'items' of 'dict' objects}
      2/1    0.000    0.000    0.000    0.000 {method 'join' of 'str' objects}
     1792    0.000    0.000    0.000    0.000 {method 'lower' of 'str' objects}
   527099    0.184    0.000    0.184    0.000 {method 'ravel' of 'numpy.ndarray' objects}
  1061862    1.935    0.000    1.935    0.000 {method 'reduce' of 'numpy.ufunc' objects}
   527099    0.272    0.000    0.272    0.000 {method 'reshape' of 'numpy.ndarray' objects}
      897    0.001    0.000    0.001    0.000 {method 'split' of '_sre.SRE_Pattern' objects}
      897    0.000    0.000    0.000    0.000 {method 'split' of 'str' objects}
        1    0.000    0.000    0.000    0.000 {method 'squeeze' of 'numpy.ndarray' objects}
      897    0.000    0.000    0.000    0.000 {method 'strip' of 'str' objects}
        1    0.000    0.000    0.000    0.000 {method 'take' of 'numpy.ndarray' objects}
        1    0.000    0.000    0.000    0.000 {next}
     7666    0.016    0.000    0.016    0.000 {numpy.core.multiarray.arange}
  1588966    0.618    0.000    0.618    0.000 {numpy.core.multiarray.array}
     7666    0.010    0.000    0.010    0.000 {numpy.core.multiarray.empty}
   527098    0.381    0.000    0.381    0.000 {numpy.core.multiarray.interp}
        1    0.000    0.000    0.000    0.000 {numpy.core.multiarray.normalize_axis_index}
        1    0.000    0.000    0.000    0.000 {open}
        2    0.000    0.000    0.000    0.000 {range}
      897    0.001    0.000    0.001    0.000 {zip}
```

---

Update: I have now run snakeviz and the output can be seen here:

[Snakeviz output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/D2quV.png)

Comment: Have you found out which exact part of your code is taking the most time? Using something like cProfile is great for that. Or are you already sure that it is the Interpolation? if that is the case, im sorry and i misunderstood you :-)

Comment: In your actual code have you done any profiling to determine where the slowdown is?

Comment: Thank you for your responses! I have now run cProfile but it's new to me so I'm not quite sure how to interpret the output? I will add it to the question as it's too long for here.

Comment: @Flob does that help?

Comment: @IanQuah does that help at all?

Comment: Visualizing this using something like Snakeviz can really help: install via `pip install snakeviz`, then use it like this : `python -m cProfile -o temp.dat <filepath>` and then `Snakeviz temp.dat`. This will show you a grafical represantation of your code where you can easily find out whats taking the most time, which functions get called by other functions and so on. Interpreting the raw cProfile output is a pain in the a*s.

Comment: Thank you @Flob! I have edited the question with the snakeviz output. If I'm reading it right, it implies that both the interpolation and integration are taking up a lot of time? I should say that I have a code in fortran that does the same calculation, but it is orders of magnitude more efficient, so this should be possible to do faster? That code uses a romberg integration function and an interpolation function called 'hunt' from numerical recipes, if that helps.